# General Central Limit Theorem for Binomial Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, characteristic-functions

> **Question**
>   Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of arbitrary binomial random variables such that $EX_n\to \infty$ and $\text{Var}(X_n)/EX_n^2\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Then 
>   show that
>   $$
> Z_n=\frac{X_n-EX_n}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(X_n)}}\stackrel{\text{d}}{\to } N(0,1).
> $$

**My attempt**

The idea of the proof is to find the characteristic function $\varphi_{n}$
of $Z_n$ and show that $\varphi_{n}(t)\to \exp(-t^2/2)$.

To this end, let $X_n\sim \text{Bin}(m_n,p_n)$. Since $\varphi_{X_n}(t)=(1-p_n+p_ne^{it})^{m_n}$ we have that
$$
\varphi_{n}(t)=\varphi_{Z_n}(t)=\exp\left(
\frac{-itm_np_n}{\sqrt{m_np_n(1-p_n)}}
\right)
\left(1-p_n+p_n\exp\left(\frac{it}{\sqrt{m_np_n(1-p_n)}}\right)\right)^{m_n}.
$$ 
At this point I tried to taylor expand the exponential terms, mimic the proof of classical clt and use the fact that if $c_j\to 0$, $a_j\to \infty$, $a_jc_j\to \lambda$, then $(1+c_j)^{a_j}\to e^{\lambda}$ as $j\to \infty$. Doing so yields for example that 
$$
1-p_n+p_n\exp\left(\frac{it}{\sqrt{m_np_n(1-p_n)}}\right)=1+p_n\frac{it}{\sqrt{m_np_n(1-p_n)}}-p_n\frac{t^2}{2(m_np_n(1-p_n))}+\dotsb
$$
and
$$
\exp\left(-\frac{itm_np_n}{\sqrt{m_np_n(1-p_n)}}\right)=1-\frac{itm_np_n}{\sqrt{m_np_n(1-p_n)}}-\frac{t^2m_n^2p_n^2}{2m_np_n(1-p_n)}+\dotsb.
$$
In the first of these we have something that resembles the term $-t^2/2$ but I can't proceed from here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unless you are required to use the characteristic function, invoking Lindeberg's condition is probably the most straightforward.

Comment: I need to use characteristic functions to  solve the problem. I can't invoke Lindeberg's condition. We are covering cfs in class.

Comment: I can only think of how to prove it using MGF's and the same $n$ and $p$ across the entire sequence.

Comment: Try working on $\ln \varphi_{n}(t)$, then Taylor expanding the logarithm, and then Taylor expanding the exponential that is left.